# 688 Hunter/Killer torpedoes not finding their targets

Tags: janes-688i-hunter-killer

I'm trying to complete the training missions in *Jane's 688(I) Hunter/Killer* and I'm having trouble hitting the training submarine targets. I've turned on active sonar and I can see the target, I load two ADCAP torpedoes and:

- Set the target
- Set the floor to be 1500ft
- Set them to enable before they reach the target (say 4500 yards)

Once they launch they head towards the target, their little target thing goes reddish but then they "conduct a turn away maneuver" and disable instead of exploding.

Comment: I don't know the game, but torpedoes normally activate either on set proximity or after maximum range traveled. Could the latter be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this only happens for the training missions! In the actual mission the torpedoes correctly find their targets.

In the training mission once the torpedo has "conducted its turn away manoeuvre" point are awards in the goals list.